# data table lapply and additional columns in output

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am just hoping there is a more convenient way. Imaging I would like to run a model with different transformations of some of the columns, e.g. winsorizing. I would like to provide the transformed data set to the model and some additional columns that do not need to be transformed. Is there a practical way to this in one line? I do not want to replace the data using `:=` because I am planning to run the model with different specifications of the transformation.

```
dt<-data.table(id=1:10, Country=sample(c("Germany", "USA"),10, replace=TRUE), x=rnorm(10,1,10),y=rnorm(10,1,10),factor=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:2],10,replace=TRUE)))
sel.col<-c("x","y")
dt[,lapply(.SD,Winsorize),.SDcols=sel.col,by=factor]
```

I would Need to call data.table again to merge the original dt with the transformed data and pay Attention to the order.

```
data.table(dt[,.(id,Country),by=factor],
           dt[,lapply(.SD,Winsorize),.SDcols=sel.col,by=factor])
```

I was hoping that I could include the additional columns with the lapply call

```
dt[,.(lapply(.SD,Winsorize), id, Country),.SDcols=sel.col,by=factor]
```

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can pass additional arguments to lapply.

Comment: lapply(.SD,Winsorize, additional_argments_for_Winsorize_function)

Comment: That I know and I am planning on doing this to winsorize with different probabilities. I want additional columns in the Output that are not used within the function

Comment: You could do `dt[, c(lapply(.SD, Winsorize), .(id, Country)), .SDcols = sel.col, by = factor]`. data.table just parses what you give it. `lapply` returns a `list`. if you want to add a vector to a `list`, you add it another `list`- otherwise each element will become a separate element in the list. Compare `c(list(1:4), 1:4)` vs `c(list(1:4), list(1:4))`. Basically, if you know how base R works, it is pretty easy to understand how to manipulate data.table too.

Comment: Thanks, but the columns `id` and `country` would lose their Name and are named `V3` and `V4`. Can I avoid that?

Comment: I could think of at-least 3 ways: either `dt[, c(lapply(.SD, Winsorize), data.table(id, Country)), .SDcols = sel.col, by = factor]` or  `cols <- c("id", "Country") ; dt[, c(lapply(.SD, Winsorize), mget(cols)), .SDcols = sel.col, by = factor]` or `dt[, c(lapply(.SD[, ..sel.col], Winsorize), .SD[, ..cols]), by = factor]` - the last one will return a few warnings that you can safely ignore. There could be some other way that could just pass it a named list but I can't think of one right now.

Comment: Thanks, your comment would be the best answer. If you post it I could accept it. To be honest to me, it does not come naturally that you would be able to do it this way, but I am glad to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you just need?

```
dt[, c(lapply(.SD,Winsorize), list(id = id, Country = Country)), .SDcols=sel.col,by=factor]
```

Unfortunately this method get's slow with big data. Apparently this was optimised in some recent update, but it still very slow.

Comment: This is basically Arenburgs comment, but to Close this I will mark your answer as accepted. THanks for the effort :)

Comment: I noticed that after posting, but reading comments is a pain, so I let it stay.  Glad to be able to contribute a little! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to merge, you can assign columns after lapply call:

```
> library(DescTools)
> library(data.table)
> dt<-data.table(id=1:10, Country=sample(c("Germany", "USA"),10, replace=TRUE), x=rnorm(10,1,10),y=rnorm(10,1,10),factor=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:2],10,replace=TRUE)))
> sel.col<-c("x","y")
> dt
    id Country          x           y factor
 1:  1 Germany  13.116248  -0.4609152      B
 2:  2 Germany  -6.623404  -3.7048052      A
 3:  3     USA -18.027532  22.2946805      A
 4:  4     USA -13.377736   6.2021252      A
 5:  5 Germany -12.585897   0.8255081      B
 6:  6 Germany  -8.816252 -12.1218135      B
 7:  7     USA  -3.459926 -11.5710316      B
 8:  8     USA   3.180706   6.3262951      B
 9:  9 Germany  -5.520637   7.2877123      A
10: 10 Germany  15.857069   8.6422997      A
> # Notice an assignment `(sel.col) :=`  here:
> dt[,(sel.col) := lapply(.SD,Winsorize),.SDcols=sel.col,by=factor]
> dt
    id Country          x           y factor
 1:  1 Germany  11.129140  -0.4609152      B
 2:  2 Germany  -6.623404  -1.7234191      A
 3:  3     USA -17.097573  19.5642043      A
 4:  4     USA -13.377736   6.2021252      A
 5:  5 Germany -11.831968   0.8255081      B
 6:  6 Germany  -8.816252 -12.0116571      B
 7:  7     USA  -3.459926 -11.5710316      B
 8:  8     USA   3.180706   5.2261377      B
 9:  9 Germany  -5.520637   7.2877123      A
10: 10 Germany  11.581528   8.6422997      A
```

Comment: See my edit. I do not want to replace the columns or create additional columns, because I am running the models with different specifications of the data Transformation function.